# Mathematica for loop data how to export to table form in latex

Tags: latex, table

I have created some data using the below code, want to export it latex in table form

```
 A=l(t^u)(x)^3; B=t^u(x + 2 l) ^3; C1=t^u(x+3l)^3; l = 3;
 For [x = 0, x <= 2, x = x + 1, For [t = 0.01, t <= 0.03, t = t + 0.02, 
              Print [u = 0.25; x, " ", t, A, B, C1, u = 0.5; 
               " ", A, " ", B " ", C1]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use `For` myself. But will leave that for you to change it if you want. I would just use Table.

But this is small modification to your code

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
A = l (t^u) (x)^3;
B = t^u (x + 2 l)^3;
C1 = t^u (x + 3 l)^3;
l = 3;
data = First@Last@Reap@For[x = 0, x <= 2, x = x + 1,
     For[t = 0.01, t <= 0.03, t = t + 0.02,
      Sow[{u = 0.25; x, " ", t, A, B, C1, u = 0.5; " ", A, " ", B " ",
         C1}]
      ]
     ]
```

And now just do

```
 TeXForm[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can export the above and compile it using Latex to give

[image]

> can you suggest how to export in scientific form or restricting the
> data to fixed decimal places

I think it will best to do this at the source, i.e. when you generate the data. For example using `Round[A,0.01]` will round the value to 2 decimal points only.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
A = l (t^u) (x)^3;
B = t^u (x + 2 l)^3;
C1 = t^u (x + 3 l)^3;
l = 3;
data = First@Last@Reap@For[x = 0, x <= 2, x = x + 1,
     For[t = 0.01, t <= 0.03, t = t + 0.02,
      Sow[{u = 0.25; x, t, Round[A, 0.01], Round[B, 0.01], 
        Round[C1, 0.01], u = 0.5; Round[A, 0.01], Round[B, 0.01], 
        Round[C1, 0.01]}]]]
```

Gives

```
TeXForm[data]

\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
 0 & 0.01 & 0. & 68.31 & 230.53 & 0. & 21.6 & 72.9 \\
 0 & 0.03 & 0. & 89.89 & 303.39 & 0. & 37.41 & 126.27 \\
 1 & 0.01 & 0.95 & 108.47 & 316.23 & 0.3 & 34.3 & 100. \\
 1 & 0.03 & 1.25 & 142.75 & 416.18 & 0.52 & 59.41 & 173.21 \\
 2 & 0.01 & 7.59 & 161.91 & 420.9 & 2.4 & 51.2 & 133.1 \\
 2 & 0.03 & 9.99 & 213.08 & 553.93 & 4.16 & 88.68 & 230.54 \\
\end{array}
\right)
```

Compiling

[image]

There are many other Mathematica commands to Format numbers you can use also. You can also use `NumberForm` like this

```
n=NumberForm[1.23432,{2,3}]
(* 1.200 *)
```

And then export `n` to TeXForm.  There is also `AccountingForm` and others. Check help for different command to format numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is working well.

Comment: can you suggest how to export in scientific form or restricting the data to fixed decimal places.

Comment: @Rag fyi, updated with one way.

Comment: Thank you. It worked well.